# Consulta por problemas con inicializador AddEventListener()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Hola tengo un problema que me comenzo a surgir, estaba creando un proyecto y en el archivo js, inicialice un AddEventListener("click") y un "new bootstrap.Modal()".

Estaba todo normal, funciona pero cuando lo llamo al archivo JS de otra pagina html, buscando algunas funciones de validaciones generales que cree, salta error bien comienza, ya que me toma el addEventListenner y el modal, ya que el sistema lo busca y no lo encuentra a los elementos, pero yo no los necesito a ellos, solo las funciones de validacion general

Comienza a saltar error, entonces mi pregunta es la siguiente.

Hay forma de que llame de otra pagina y lo evite a los inicializadores?, o tengo que separarlo de los archivos a las funciones y exportarlo uno por uno?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El HTML se lee en orden, si tu pones el script antes de la creación  del elemento 'modal-vertical', el script no va a encontrar ese elemento, porque aún no existe. Entonces 1) Reordena tu código adecuadamente o 2) Utiliza eventos para detectar que la página ya tiene todos sus elementos cargados ej: `DOMContentLoaded ` y mi favorita 3) Usar el atributo onclick en vez del AddEventListener("click"), menos rollo menos lio y funciona siempre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifica antes de ejecutar esas funciones si el elemento existe en la página mediante un condicional tipo:

```
if(document.getElementById('modal-verificar)) {
  // aqui va el código de tu modal
}
```

y si no existe se saltará ese código y no te dará más errores.